# ColdFusion not handles HTTP OPTIONS requests for CFC

Tags: ajax, extjs, coldfusion

Scenario:

- A webserver which hosts a frontend application based on ExtJS.
- A ColdFusion 10 server (with Apache) that hosts backend services.
- Frontend application make AJAX requests to ColdFusion components (CFC) with form `http://<CF_server>/<app_path>/<CFC>?method=someMethod&...`
- CFC responds with JSON.

Since frontend and backend are on different servers we are in a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) environment and AJAX requests making two http requests to backend: first is an OPTIONS method for handshake and second is a POST request. I have need enabling headers in Apache on CF server and using "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" directive for enabling CORS, but I would like handling headers programmatically from CF not Apache. I have run some test and I noticed that OPTIONS method in http request works only with CFM and not with CFC, so the first AJAX request (with OPTIONS method) fails. I can bypass OPTIONS request in AJAX call setting useDefaultXhrHeader properties, but I would understand CF behavior.

After running tests with cfhttp tag I have found that:

- HTTP request with OPTIONS method to CFM are similar to GET method: triggers events method on Application.cfc (orRequestStart, ...), returns filecontent and headers.
- HTTP request with OPTIONS method to CFC don't triggers events, don't return filecontent nor headers.
- A call (with OPTSIONS method) to unexistants CFC return same result.

Why CF not handle OPTIONS method when calling CFC?

In my tests i have bypassed Apache using integrated CF webserver on port 8500. I have also tried on CF9 with same results. Railo, instead, has a different behavior: handles OPTIONS method also for CFC.

This is similar as this thread without response: http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:59715

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same kind of issue with both CF and Apache CXF recently.

It seems CF has no defined behavior for verbs other that GET and POST. In my case, I installed the CORS filter here: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html

That intercepts the requests and handles them before they make it as far as your app. It worked for CXF and should work for CF, but the downside is that it requires a change to your web.xml, which may not be allowed in certain hosting setups.

The other option is to configure apache to add the necessary headers: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

I also found a number of differences between browser vendors in when they use an OPTIONS call. I can't remember the specifics, but test early cross-browser if that's an eventual requirement.